# Detect Clipboard changes in Windows OS

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to detect when clipboard changes in Windows, the change could come from any application in the machine. How can I achieve this in C++ (or C)?

Comment: Your looking for the [WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) message.

Comment: Check MS sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard

Comment: @Jabberwocky Will that message trigger if the user copy something from other application (not from my app)?

Comment: @KimTrongNguyen I suppose so, otherways the message wouldn't make much sense

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you so much! look like this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It seems that you need to use `AddClipboardFormatListener` in order to obtain that message from the OS.

Answer (score 4):

Per MSDN documentation:

[Using the Clipboard: Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents)

> Monitoring Clipboard Contents
>
> There are three ways of monitoring changes to the clipboard. The oldest method is to [**create a clipboard viewer window**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#creating-a-clipboard-viewer-window). Windows 2000 added the ability to [**query the clipboard sequence number**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#querying-the-clipboard-sequence-number), and Windows Vista added support for [**clipboard format listeners**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#creating-a-clipboard-format-listener). Clipboard viewer windows are supported for backward compatibility with earlier versions of Windows. New programs should use clipboard format listeners or the clipboard sequence number.

The same page explains each step in detail, but to recap:

- call [`SetClipboardViewer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboardviewer) and then listen for [`WM_CHANGECBCHAIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-changecbchain) and [`WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-drawclipboard) window messages.
- or, call [`GetClipboardSequenceNumber()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboardsequencenumber) periodically, or at least just when you want to check if the clipboard has changed since your last check.
- or, call [`AddClipboardFormatListener()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) and then listen for [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) window messages.